# How can I make top menu navigation multilingual?

Tags: top-link-bar, multilingual

I have a site that uses managed metadata for top navigation.

The metadata is set with several languages but when I switch the language of SharePoint my top navigation doesn't change.

What am i doing wrong?

I have made a termset

Store; About; Contact

I have defined a scond language as Danish.
I have filled out the labels with Danish names for the 3 terms.
I have said that i want the metadata do be in Danish by default.
I updated my timerjobs for metadata and nothing happens.

however if i remove the English language, save and then add the English to my solution again the temrs are in Danish.
If i then say the default metadata language is englist the terms change over to English.
When i do this im back to step 1.
As i see it there is no way of changing the navigation from English to a different language but there is a way to "cheat" so that the language can be forced.
Having hard time figuring out why to use metadata top navigation when the menus dont dynamically change to the language of my choice.

Comment: After reading some guides about creating multilingual subsites I have come to understand that it should be possible OOTB using Managed Metadata with Variations in SharePoint 2013. I don't really understand how it works as I haven't got a change to test/try anything with it but you could check if you get any pointers from this article: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/08/19/using-managed-metadata-with-variations-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx. Also here is a long article about multilingual features in SP: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805087(v=office.15).aspx. :-)

Comment: Also have you checked that the users have correct language defined in their profile if that affects anything? :-)

Comment: @Tenttu the users have the correct settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variations (or just standalone sites created in different languages) in combination with multi-language managed navigation.

For example you can have your navigation termset with terms in English, French and Danish (default English). Next you create 3 subsites in 3 different languages. Each of these subsites uses a separate navigation termset. The English site uses the original created termset, the other sites use their own termset but these other termsets reuse the terms of the original termset (with variations enabled this behavior is added automatically for you).

The 2 main points are: create subsites with the language that you want the navigation terms to appear in (user language settings have no influance) and use a different termset for each site which reuses terms form the original termset.